# Laravel 8 fresh install show directory structure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

[image]

Instead of run project it showing directory

Comment: the docroot/webroot of the site should be pointing to the `public` folder, that is where the `index.php` file is

Comment: localhost/prim/public/   you can run it like that

Comment: @lagbox   I know i can run from public directory but i want to directly run from http://localhost/prim/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow below 2 step to overcome with this issue

- Rename **server.php** to **index.php**
- Move **.htaccess** from public directory to root directory

Comment: @MaahiBhat What is the error showing?  Check after restarting the server

Comment: I dont know why but it's adding folder name twice. localhost/mywebsite/mywebsite

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal and run "php artisan serve" command. It will give you a link like localhost:8000. This will be your home link. Please go to the documentation and look at the steps.

Answer (score 0):

First You should open the `public` Directory in your browser like this: `localhost/prime/public` Then You need to set your environment setting in your `.env` file in your root project.